# MSSQL Timeout error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm using MSSQL Server 2008. I have to work with **several databases at a time**. Some tomes the system gives an error "Transaction Timeout" when the **insert** or **update** records. But it works after a few minute.
There are **few users are using differences windows applications** to manipulate data in databases.
I want to know, 
is there any relation between this issue and multiple database usage ?
[image]
Is this query type (multiple database linked in a query) will effect to the Timeout ?

Comment: Are you using it directly or through some kind of client application?

Comment: Using client application. There are several client applications.

Comment: C# windows form applications

Answer (score 1):

Highly depends on the timeout's reason. Frequently it is caused when resources are locked by one application and the second application waits too long. Multiple databases, even in single instance, are using Distibuted Transaction Coordinator.

> A transaction within a single instance of the Database Engine that
>   spans two or more databases is actually a distributed transaction. The
>   instance manages the distributed transaction internally; to the user,
>   it operates as a local transaction.
>   [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856598(v=sql.110).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856598%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

And the DTC is much slower than working in the scope of the same database, so it causes data to be locked for a wider timeframe and might cause timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `Transaction` you may want to check and set each of these timeout property to manage properly your application behaviour.

See [TransactionOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enterpriseservices.transactionoption%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `IsolationLevel` and `TimeOut` (the first one maybe has to be `Required`)

See [SqlCommand.CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you're using commands.

A good way to use transaction could be

```
TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300); // 5 minutes

using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, timeout))
{
        // Code ...
}
```

Keep in mind that a lot of concurrent transactions could affect SQL Server efficiency. Maybe you need different instances of the same Server to use it properly, but the cons come with synchronization of each instance.